# Javascript: Select objects with partially known name

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to select objects using RegEx?

There are many objects that start with 'ctx',  I just want the ones that are followed by a **random** number.

My goal is to iterate through an array of objects and submit them as a variable in function.

Example Object Names:
ctx
**ctx7**
**ctx49**
**ctx103**
ctxFilter
ctxVPS
ctxFromRow
.....

```
var ctxs = [ctx7,ctx49,ctx103];  // Get Objects Here
ctxs.forEach(function(entry){
    var evtAjax = {
        currentCtx: entry,
        csrAjaxRefresh: true
    };
    AJAXRefreshView(evtAjax, SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
});
```

Comment: You should redesign your system so that you don't need to do that.  In particular, objects don't actually have names.

Comment: @SLaks well i cant see nothing wrong with it as long as each object has name property ;)

Comment: What data structure do you have? with what values?

Comment: I'm augmenting the default behavior of a SharePoint page.  The objects I'm after do have a property called 'ctxId' with the random number as the value.